# Spread sweave command through multiple lines

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, bioconductor

How can I spread this sweave line in several (to avoid 80 char limit complain in bioconductor) ?

```
<<echo=F, fig.align='center', fig.cap='some plot with long label', fig.height=4, fig.width=10>>=
```

So I tried this..

```
<<echo=F,
 fig.align='center',
 fig.cap='some plot with long label',
 fig.height=4,
 fig.width=10>>=
```

But it doesnt work...

Comment: Sorry, but it is by design. I think you can explain it to Bioconductor. Sigh, I feel it is a little aggressive for them to check the line width in Rnw vignettes (if it is true)... The freedom of choice of line width should be a basic human right.